# Is setting pointer to NULL and emptying the char array required here?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In the following code snippet I'm taking two inputs from `stdin` using `fgets()` and `strtol`. The two inputs get saved in different variables. In order to read in the user input I need a couple of variables for `fgets()` and `strtol()`. Here is a verbose solution using different variables for the two calls to `fgets()` and `strtol()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    long int m_row;
    long int n_col;

    char rows_save[sizeof(long int)];
    char *ptr_rows_save;
    printf("Enter number of rows:\n");
    if (fgets(rows_save, sizeof(rows_save), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        m_row = strtol(rows_save, &ptr_rows_save, 10);

    }

    char cols_save[sizeof(long int)];
    char *ptr_cols_save;
    printf("Enter number of columns:\n");
    if (fgets(cols_save, sizeof(cols_save), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        n_col = strtol(cols_save, &ptr_cols_save, 10);

    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see, I am using a new array and a new pointer to an array for each number the program receives from stdin. I tried avoiding this for exercise purposes (or for fun for that matter). To achieve this I am using a single char array and a single pointer to an array but keeping the two separate calls to `fgets()` and `strtol()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    long int m_row;
    long int n_col;

    char save[sizeof(long int)];
    char *ptr_save;
    printf("Enter number of rows:\n");
    if (fgets(save, sizeof(save), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        m_row = strtol(save, &ptr_save, 10);
        ptr_save = NULL;
        save[0] = '\0';
    }

    printf("Enter number of columns:\n");
    if (fgets(save, sizeof(save), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        n_col = strtol(save, &ptr_save, 10);
        ptr_save = NULL;
        save[0] = '\0';
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To be on the safe side, I set the pointer `*ptr_save` to `NULL` and cleared the character array by setting the first element to `\0` after I have read in the user input and processed it with `strtol()`. But would the code be equally safe if I did not set the pointer to `NULL` and cleared the character array? (For those wondering, the user input will be checked later on in the code.)

Comment: Side note: with `char save[sizeof(long int)]`, you are limiting the user-input to somewhere between 1 to 7 characters (3 on most platforms, but it is platform dependent in general). Is that really your intention???

Comment: P.S., I'm up-voting, because the question is written and explained well, and even if it includes some basic conceptual errors, it most certainly does not deserve a down-vote (especially without leaving any comment explaining it - I despite those in particular).

Comment: Thanks, @barakmanos. For learning purposes, could you point out what my basic conceptual errors in this code are?

Comment: I think they're already explained pretty well explained in the two answers below.

Comment: Sorry @barakmanos, I totally missed your first question. My original intention was to limit the user input to exactly one long integer i.e. a single number.

Comment: Well, there you go - that is a basic conceptual error. `sizeof(long int)` is the size of the memory allocated for this type of variable, **not** the length of it's decimal representation. This size depends on the platform (compiler) being used. It is mostly 4 or 8, but I've seen embedded platforms with it being 2. In either case, you **should not** rely on this size for your definition of the `save` array, which is designated to store a the (null-terminated) string representing the number in decimal base.

Comment: I'm just puzzled how I should safely determine the required size of `save` when I want the user to be able to input any integer.

Comment: The largest integer that can fit into `unsigned long int` is 2^64-1. This is a 20-digit number, so you can safely allocate your array to 20+1 characters (+1 for the null-character). For `signed long int`, it is 19 digits, but you should also account for the `-` character, so the overall amount of memory required is still 20+1 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documentation for [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) and [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

Since you are not actually using `endptr` (`ptr_save`, I mean), there is no point setting it to `NULL`... and you are (correctly) passing `&ptr_save` to `strtol()`, so `strtol()` won't care that you set `ptr_save` to `NULL`. In fact, in the example given where you are not doing anything with `ptr_save`, you could just pass `NULL` directly to `strtol()` and not use a variable... however, you should use `ptr_save` properly and check what it points afterwards to to verify the results of `strtol()`. You should also be clearing `errno` before each `strtol()` call and checking it afterwards - this is the only way to detect range and base errors.

`fgets()` does not care about `NULL`s, leading or otherwise, in the buffer, and if something goes wrong during the call there is no guarantee your leading `NULL` will still be there. You should check the result of `fgets()` to see if it succeeded or failed, not gamble on a `NULL` remaining at the start of the buffer.

Also, `sizeof(long int)` returns the number of bytes taken by a `long`... which is not the maximum number of characters required to represent a long in base 10.

Last, within the scope of this function, `ptr_save` will be valid after a *successful* `strtol()` and `save` will be correctly null-terminated after a *successful* `fgets()`... so provided you check the results, there is no safety gained by writing nulls in either case.

Comment: Thanks. `strol()` stores the address of the first invalid character in `*ptr_save`. I could use this to check if the user entered a correct number or made a typo (e.g. `12as`). But then again, I would need two separate pointers for the two `strol()` calls and not set the pointers to `NULL` I guess.

Comment: @brauner No, use one pointer, check right after the first `strtol()` to see if it succeeded, then check again right after the next one to see if that succeeded. If `strtol()` fails it will set `endptr` accordingly, not leave it with whatever value you passed in.

Comment: You should also be clearing `errno` before each `strtol()` and checking it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

setting a pointer to nil doesn't destroy the memory it points to. you only 'abadon' it. In this case though your points points to your char[] anyway WHICH is memory allocated on the stack and so it gets freed when you leave the function.

depending on your needs that may be ok?!